# Convert an object to a array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I received this from an Ajax call in my PHP page:

```
[{"id":8},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12}]
```

How can I parse it in order to have something like this :

```
array(8, 10, 11, 12)
```

Thanks.

Comment: See the dupe pass `true`, then you can use `array_values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for that:

```
<?php
$array = json_decode( '[{"id":8},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12}]' );
function getId($n) {
    return($n->id);
}
$mapped = array_map("getId", $array);
var_dump($mapped);
?>
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e74f6252bcf9b321115af8626ca7ebc192414730

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decode your json to an array, then iterate it and grab your values. Something like this.

```
<?php

$json = '[{"id":8},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12}]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$result = array_map(static function ($el) {
    return $el['id'];
}, $array);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's look what you have here.

`[{"id":8},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":12}]` is the json representation of an array that contains objects. We can use the function [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the data out of such a json representation.
`var_dump(json_decode($json));`
would look like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(8)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(11)
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(12)
  }
}
```

But now let's have a look a the docs. `json_decode` has more than one parameter. The second parameter states if objects should be converted to associative arrays.
So `var_dump(json_decode($json, true));` would give us something like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(8)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(11)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(12)
  }
}
```

But now we want to have the value of every of these arrays. While we could do this with a simple loop, PHP has a [lot of inbuilt array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). So let's look, what could be working for us.

Let's take [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). This function takes a callable (could be function) and an array and returns an array. (For details visit the docs.)

```php
$result = array_map(function ($value) {
    return $value['id'];
}, json_decode($json, true));

var_dump($result);
```

This would give us

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(8)
  [1]=>
  int(10)
  [2]=>
  int(11)
  [3]=>
  int(12)
}
```

Explanation: We replace every array in the array with the id value in the array.